# WebSocket подключение с VPN

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, vpn

Сервер Tomcat 8 (Java EE). Машина Ubuntu 16.04.

Сокет клиента подключается ([гайд](https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets)) к серверному сокету ([гайд](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/12/websocket-multiple-users-encoders-decoders-dogs/)) - ошибок нет. Клиент получает и отправляет данные.

**Но.**

Если включен впн (тестировалось на Opera VPN) соединение разрывается через пару секунд после успешного подключения. Проблема выявлена на Windows 10 (Браузер Opera с её встроенным VPN) и на Apple Mac Book (Любой браузер).

Использую `ws` подключение. Говорили что `wss` может решить эту проблему, это так?

Какие ещё варианты решения проблемы?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [WebSocket и VPN](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766427/websocket-%d0%b8-vpn)

Comment: @kff да.Тут более развернуто. И тот вопрос далеко уже.

Comment: @Tsyklop Нехорошо дубликаты плодить. Лучше либо удалите старый вопрос, либо дополните его развернутыми сведениями.